# Sitrecore MinValue

Tags: sitecore, min

I need to sort very large number of item in Sitecore.
So I used negative number, something like this:

```cs
item.sortOrder = int.MinValue + someId
```

minValue = -2147483647
but sitecore sort correctly only for value greater then -2143053648 so there is a difference of 4430001
so now my code is

```cs
item.sortOrder = int.MinValue + 4430001 + someId
```

and it sorts correctly

does anyone ever experienced something like this, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you need such large numbers? Sitecore recommends no more than 100 items at any level in the tree.

Comment: there aren't more then 100 item in one folder, but the order is cross folder.

Comment: what we are sorting are all the article of the italian constitution. it's a very complex structure. Many books each one contains chapters, with section... and the sorting is supposed to be throw chapters and section

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but it would be better to define a public constant for Sitecore SortOrder Minimum value somewhere accessible.

```cs
public const int SortOrderMinimumValue = -2143053648;
```

And then reference like this

```cs
item.Fields["__Sortorder"].Value = SortOrderMinimumValue + someId;
```

That way the minimum value can be accessed any other code and can be altered at one location should you want to change the minimum value for your sorting.

To sort Items by sort order you then will need to do the following

```cs
public class ItemComparer : IComparer
{
    public int CompareSortOrder(Item item1, Item item2)
    {
        int sortOrder1;
        bool parsed1 = int.TryParse(item1["__Sortorder"], out sortOrder1);

        int sortOrder2;
        bool parsed2 = int.TryParse(item2["__Sortorder"], out sortOrder2);

        if (!parsed1 || !parsed2)
            throw new Exception("Sort order value is incorrect type");

        if (sortOrder1 < sortOrder2)
            return -1;
        if (sortOrder1 > sortOrder2)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

And then reference the code when sorting;

```cs
var itemComparer = new ItemComparer();
items.Sort(itemComparer.CompareSortOrder);
```

Comment: the problem is not with the code, on sitecore I found the exactly same value the code calculate...

Comment: thank yout jRobbins but the problem is not with the code, on sitecore I found the exactly same value I've calculated with that code, or some code really close to that... But when it comes to sort item according to the sortorder, I've found that value closer to int.Minvalue doesn't work, item goes straight to last position